# Undeclared Identifier (newGame) - Pointer to function as argument

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm unsure what my compiler wants here. It gives me the following error

```
error C2065: 'newGame' : undeclared identifier
```

Relevant code:

```
void createMenu() {
    MenuItem newGameOption = MenuItem("../art/newGame.bmp", newGame);
}
//start a new game
void newGame() {

}
```

In MenuItem.h

```
class MenuItem {
    bool selected = false;
    std::string path; //Path to menu item's art

    void *pf(); //Function to execute upon selection

public :
    MenuItem(const char*, void pf()); //constructor
};
```

Comment: Declare `newGame()` above `createMenu()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error seems to be fairly straightforward. Whatever "newGame" is, the compiler knows nothing about it. It's the first time it seen anything of that name.

The fact that you have a newGame() function defined later in the file, apparently, doesn't help. At the time that the compiler tries to compile the first function, it hasn't read it.

Here's some Google food for you: "forward declarations". Put:

```
void newGame();
```

Before createMenu(), so that the compiler knows what it is.

Comment: For some reason that gives me a whole host of new errors. Gonna add them to original question

Comment: Fixed it ignore...Thanks!